# How to show exact values in a legend with different colors in a bubble plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following data:

```
RW    GA    Freq
0     0     9
0     3     1
0     14    1
2     30    1
15    30    2
24    30    7
30    29    16
30    30    29
```

I would like to generate a bubble plot for these data, and to do that I have written the following R script:

```
df <- read.csv("/home/Desktop/data.csv")
p <- ggplot(df, aes(x=RW, y=GA, size=Freq)) + geom_point(alpha=0.7) + 
    scale_size(range = c(1, 10), name="Freq", limits=c(1,30), breaks=c(1,10,30))
```

This generates the following plot:

[image]

What I want is to show the exact unique values of `Freq` in the legend where each circle represents a value with a different color. In this case, the legend should show 6 circles for the values 1,2,7,9,16,29 (It's better to not do that manually) and each circle has a different color.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to expand the legend, you will need to define the desired breaks,  In this case, I used the `unique` function to collect the list of values.

```
library(ggplot2)

df<-structure(list(RW = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 15L, 24L, 30L, 30L), 
                   GA = c(0L, 3L, 14L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 29L, 30L), 
                   Freq = c(9L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 7L, 16L, 29L)), 
              class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -8L))

lbreaks<-sort(unique(df$Freq))

p <- ggplot(df, aes(x=RW, y=GA, size=Freq)) + geom_point(alpha=0.7) + 
  scale_size(range = c(1, 10), name="Freq", limits=c(1,30), breaks=lbreaks)
print(p)
```

[image]

**Edit:** To have a different color to, you can add `color=Freq` to the aes definition.

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=RW, y=GA, size=Freq, color=as.factor(Freq))) + geom_point(alpha=0.7) + 
  scale_size(range = c(1, 10), name="Freq", limits=c(1,30), breaks=lbreaks) +
  scale_color_discrete(name="Freq", breaks=lbreaks)
```

Comment: Thanks. Is it possible to give each circle a different colour?